# Addressing XML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a xml doxument that looks like this:

```
<create>
 <customers>
  <customer>
   <first-name>foo</first-name>
   <last-name>bar</last-name>
   ...
  </customer>
  ...
 </customers>
</create>
```

How can I address a single node, which appears several times? I've alredy tried this but it isn't working

```
var text = xmlDocument.find('customer')[0].text();
// do something
```

Following code is working but is inappropiate:

```
xmlDocument.find('customer').each(function() {
   var text = $(this).text();
   // do something
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var text = xmlDocument.find('customer').first().text();
```

or

```
var text = xmlDocument.find('customer:first').text();
```

or

```
var text = xmlDocument.find('customer').eq(0).text();
```

`[0]` selects the underlying DOM node, not the jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks for this really fast answer :)